# Remove "or Drop files" section/part from file upload button in Lightning web component

Tags: file-upload, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

Hi is there any way of removing this "or drop files" part from the lightning file upload button ?
In the below screen shot i want to remove the "or drop file" section and only keep the button and functionality as such...
is this possible ?

tried Using this:

.html code:

```
/* <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
  <lightning-input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv, .png, .doc, .docx, .pdf"
   onchange={openfileUpload}>
  </lightning-input>
```

in css file:

```
.THIS .slds-file-selec`enter code here`tor__dropzone .slds-file-selector__text{
display: none !important;
```

}

but didn't worked.
is there any workaround ?

[Upload button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLUr4.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that due to LWC [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom) which ensures both CSS and Element isolation.

> CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child

You're allowed to modify only what is defined in your component.
Since the element with `slds-file-selector__text` class is defined inside the `lightning-input` component you have no access and you cannot override its style.

You could create your own component without the "or drop file" part starting from the [blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/file-selector/).

---

A standard LWC could set a CSS property using [`var()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var), which takes two arguments: a custom identifier and an optional fallback value.
In such cases you can override LWC CSS property via [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/).

I.E.
The `background-color` of a [lightning-badge](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-badge/documentation) is defined as follow:

```css
background-color: var(--sds-c-badge-color-background,#ecebea);
```

Therefore you can change its background creating a custom css class that sets a value for the token `--sds-c-badge-color-background`

```css
.orange-badge {
    --sds-c-badge-color-background: orange;
}
```

```html
<lightning-badge label="orange" class="orange-badge"> </lightning-badge>
```

Here's a [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Rt8qxrLDsapEMVW6Vsqi/src/app.html?p=stories)

Sadly `lightning-input` doesn't use var() function.

Comment: but in the case of a combobox, we can override the input class and change the input colour right ? by defining a style element in rendered callback, so is there any workaround for this also ?

Comment: @Gon You can override LWC CSS properties defined using `var()` via Styling Hooks. I updated the answer. Anyway there is no workaround for `lightning-input`.